# Changing header style on scroll using intersectionObserver and fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I'm a newbie of front-end development. I'm currently working on a project trying to make my header style change while scrolling using intersectionObserver. I'm also using fullpage.js to create a full page transition effect. However, I encounter the problem that when I scroll, browser considers section 1 and section2 are the same section, which the header style will only change when I scroll to the section3.
Would anyone tell me what happened? Maybe I missed something.

The code I used is here:

````
 <div class="header">
        <a href="#">
            <h1>logo<h1>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-link">
                <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
          
   <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section s1">
        </div>
        
        <div class="section s2">
        </div>
        <div class="section s3">
    
        </div>
        <div class="section s4">
        </div>

    </div>       
          
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.min.js"></script>```
````

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #070520;
}
.header {
  --text: #fff;
  --background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 1rem 6.5rem 0 1.5rem;
  background-color: var(--background);
}


.header a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text);
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}


.header .nav-link {
  list-style: none;
}

.header .nav-link li {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.header-scrolled {
  --text: #070520;
}

.s2 {
  background-color: grey;
}

.s3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.s4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
new fullpage("#fullpage", {
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
});

const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const sectionOne = document.querySelector('.s1');

const sectionOneOptions = {};

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries,sectionOneObserver){
    entries.forEach(entry=>{
       if(!entry.isIntersecting){
           header.classList.add('header-scrolled')
       }else{
           header.classList.remove('header-scrolled')
       }
    })
},sectionOneOptions);

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne);
```

https://codepen.io/Austin020304/pen/WNwjqaO

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) or [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) for that.

Also, do not forget to check the callbacks examples:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples

You might also want to check [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=5s) I did making use of  the state classes to create animations.